# How can I darken my ARSKView?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have been working on an Augmented Reality game, and I am implementing my pause menu. I have the pause menu fully working, with a UIView that appears as another layer on top of the ARSKView. However, I would like to darken the ARSKView when the pause menu is shown, and then return it to its original state when the pause menu is dismissed. I have tried the obvious line:

```
sceneView.tintColor = .black
```

when the pause button is pressed, but this didn't work as I thought it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tintColor is actually used for the color of controls and not to change the background.  You should set your pause menu view to be full screen with a semi transparrent [backgroundColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622591-backgroundcolor) equal to something like UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.75) to put a 25% gray over the background view.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed. Not something I'd exactly considered either! Thank you.